# How to validate data with usage logic in Azure mobile service

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

My problem is how do I validate data. I don't know JS, so I tried do in this way:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

   if(typeof item.NamePlayer!=='empty') // in app default value is 'empty'
   {

      request.execute();
   }
}
```

Does JS have a contain method on a table? For example I want a response to table 'NamePlayer' and not add an item with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition will *always* be true. The operator `typeof` will return one of the following values: "number," "string," "boolean," "object," "function," and "undefined." - so it will never be "empty". If you want to check whether the item.NamePlayer is not empty, you can use the condition below:

```
if (item.NamePlayer !== '') {
   // ...
}
```

You can also simplify the condition, which will also catch the case where the client didn't send a NamePlayer value in the input:

```
if (item.NamePlayer) {
    // ...
}
```

One more thing: your script will only dealing with the "positive" case; it also needs to send a response in case the condition fails. Something like the code below:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    if (item.NamePlayer) {
        request.execute();
    } else {
        request.respond(400, 'NamePlayer is required');
    }
}
```